# HAProxy using URL parameters for selecting a server

Tags: haproxy, sticky-sessions

We have a mobile game client running on websocket connections and we want to use HAProxy as a load balancer. There are two main conditions:

1. Set sticky session based on url parameter ID (varying string between 32 to 64 chars) and then select server based on least connections
2. If there is no ID parameter select the first or default server

Here is the sample configuration for handling first condition:

```
backend app
balance     leastconn
stick-table type string len 64 size 5M expire 30m
stick store-request url_param(ID) table app
stick on url_param(ID) table app
server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
```

The problem is sticky session doesn't work as expected and doesn't connect to last connected server. 
Can you provide any suggestions to improve it and ideally satisfy the second condition?

We are using HAProxy version 1.8.17 provided with CentOS SCL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you examined what's actually being stored in the stick table?

Comment: No, I will check it out.